# $http.get call with multiple json files on search functionality

Tags: angularjs, json, search

i want to develop search functionality which has five  categories like all,banks,auto, property and insurance. by default all(category name) tab will be active  and if i am trying to search i should able to search from all categories which i have. i have four json files for four categories.

```
any help will be really appreciated.


//code
app.controller('PageCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter','$http','$q', function    ($scope, filterFilter,$http,$q) {
    $scope.items= [];


function getFirstJson() {
    return $http.get("data.json");
}


function getSecondJson() {
    return $http.get("auto.json");
}

function getthirdJson() {
    return $http.get("auto.json");
}

function getfourthJson() {
    return $http.get("auto.json");
}
}]);
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise on what your exact problem is?

Comment: hi FKutsche , i am not able to get the results from all  four json files when i am traying to seach

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to is to make a call to all 4 of your endpoints and resolve them at the same time. This can be done with the angular $q library.

```
$q.all([
  getFirstJson(),
  getSecondJson(),
  getThirdJson(),
  getFourthJson()
])
.then(function(resp1, resp2, resp3, resp4) {
  $scope.items.push(resp1);
  $scope.items.push(resp2);
  $scope.items.push(resp3);
  $scope.items.push(resp4);
});
```

This will wait for all of the responses to resolve then push their results onto the items array.